# Thread safe method in multi threaded environment

Tags: c#, multithreading, object, thread-safety

Please let me know below method is thread safe or not. Please consider this method called in side `Timers.timer` tick event( which is a multithreaded environment).

```
public void GetMyInfo()
{

    Test t= new Test();
    string result= t.SendData();

    if (result != "0")
    {
        MyInfo _omy = new MyInfo();
        _omy.name="abc";
        _omy.age="23";
        t.sendMyInfo(_omy)
    }
}

class MyInfo
{
string name{get;set;}
string age {get;set}
}
```

`

Comment: Thread safety can have many meanings. Take a look at [Eric Lippert's blog entry about it](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/10/19/what-is-this-thing-you-call-thread-safe.aspx).

Comment: There's not enough information here, what do the methods, properties, and constructors look like? Please read http://sscce.org/.

Comment: there was a mistake i have corrected it.

Comment: Something else to consider is how long `GetMyInfo` takes to execute. If it consistently takes longer than your timer period, then you not only have the potential of multiple timer ticks happening at once (thus, multiple threads), but you have the bigger problem of new threads being created faster than the old ones are disposed. This will eventually cause your program to crash, or the machine to lock up because it's thrashing with all the thread switching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of the code you presented will share data between different threads, so you should be good, **assuming there are no thread safety issues in the relevant code that you did not post** which includes the contents of `Test()`, `Test.SendData`, and `Test.sendMyInfo`.

Now on the other hand, did you also consider the process you are sending the data to? Will it cause problems if you have two threads sending data at the same time, or will your recipient handle that properly?

Comment: If GetMyInfo() called by two thread same time . how will object reference work because i am creating 't' object reference for both threads and there will be only one object reference for a object from one name.

Comment: Each time `new Test()` is executed it will create a new object reference. So there will be two `t` objects in memory, one for each thread.

Comment: But my qz is all these object will be created on heap so how the same object reference name find-out the correct object that it refers to

Comment: Same object can have same named object reference is this becoz of each thread is having their own stack

Comment: Yes, each thread has its own stack, so each one can reference its own `t` on the heap.

Answer (score 0):

If the Test.SendData and Test.sendMyInfo methods are thread-safe, than the code you're presenting will itself be thread-safe. Otherwise no!

Comment: because i am creating a new object inside the method and calling via that object . i believe this is thread safe.

Comment: That might not be true. Consider the situation in which any of the afore-mentioned Test class methods use: data from static variables, call any method from another class which is not thread-safe, use unmanaged system resources, etc...